# Cross-domain user bouncing

Tags: http, cross-domain

So I have a number of client websites, running a service catalogue for net services, the visitor visits these and order them, now we want to enable direct activation of these services, so we need to identify the visitor in my clients own network.

So I'm using an IFRAME to load a resource from a server inside the network, that can identify the customer, and then redirects back to my script with an identification string.

Now, iframe isn't ideal for cross domain stuff, so what options do I have? I need the users browser to make a HTTP request to another server

Comment: Cross origin request must be enabled for this. I need to know the programming language you are using.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal How is this important? It's not my script that should access the remote server, it's the users browser. I'm using PHP, and the remote end may use whatever

Comment: Well, it must be enabled on the remote server which users will access.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal I was under the impression that the limiting factor here was the users web browser, that may or may not allow cross-domain requests, not whether the remote server would accept it. Either way, assume that the remote server would accept it, or the ones developing that part have to make sure it does.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the script on the remote server

```
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: This will make any browser access another domain inside an iframe for instance?

Comment: Yes. It will make any browser access another domain inside an iframe.